# How to apply an expression towards only numbers and not strings

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This should be an easy one but I'm having a brain fart today.
so..

```
var cat = {
name: 'catcat',
age: 6,
color:'brown'
}
```

I want to return an object where only numbers get squared.  So far I have..

```
function squareNumValues(object) {
    var newObj = {};
    if (object[key] = number)                  
    for (var key in object) {
        newObj.push(Math.pow(object[key],2));
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

So I want this new object to look like this:

```
var cat = {
name: 'catcat',
age: 36,
color:'brown'
}
```

On line 3 I have 
if (object[key]) = number, which I know is incorrect but I feel like I'm on the right path. Any recommendations? Thanks!

edit: also I'm supposed to use the typeof operator here.

Comment: `typeof` .........

Comment: `for (var prop in cat) typeof cat[prop] === "number" && (cat[prop] = Math.pow(cat[prop],2));`

Answer (score 2):

Beside the check for

```
if (typeof object[key] === 'number') {
```

you need another assignment to the object, because objects get their properties with direct assignment to the property, like

```
newObj[key]    = ... // property accessor with brackets and a variable
newObj['name'] = ... // property accessor with brackets and a string
newObj.name    = ... // property accessor with dot, same as above
```

and not with `push`, which is a method of array.

```
newObj[key] = Math.pow(object[key], 2);
```

```js
function squareNumValues(object) {
    var newObj = {};        
    for (var key in object) {
        if (typeof object[key] === 'number') {
            newObj[key] = Math.pow(object[key], 2);
        } else {
            newObj[key] = object[key];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}
var cat = {
        name: 'catcat',
        age: 6,
        color: 'brown'
    };

console.log(squareNumValues(cat));
```

A compacter version with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `?:`.

```js
function squareNumValues(object) {
    var newObj = {};
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        newObj[k] = typeof object[k] === 'number' ? 
            Math.pow(object[k], 2) :
            object[k];
    });
    return newObj;
}
var cat = { name: 'catcat', age: 6, color: 'brown' };

console.log(squareNumValues(cat));
```

Comment: `new Number(6)` is a valid number but typeof returns `object`. Something like `|| object[key] instanceof Number` would be nice for such instances or I'd sooner use `!isNaN`

Comment: @Ultimater it's not a "valid" number (not even sure where does the definition of a "valid number" comes from), it's an object (as per the standard and ES type system).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use function named **isNaN()** (*is Not a Number*) to determine if given value is Number or not.

Comment: not really, for the values for `null` or `true`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Examples

Comment: That's wrong: `isNaN` function is designed to check whether the value is exactly of the value `NaN`. `NaN` has nothing to do with a value being a number or not. https://zerkmsit.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/nan-is-not-a-not-a-number/